# How Can I Have More Than 8 Sims?

Tags: the-sims-3

I have had the Sims 3 for a while now and was wondering how to have more than 8 Sims in one household.  I wanted to create a large mansion and have lots of people in it and a hotel but I can't find a way past this limitation of 8 people.  I am assuming that this can be done with either a mod or a console command but I am not sure which one.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some information taken from http://nraas.wikispaces.com/Which+Mod+FAQ#Overstuffed

---

With mods, you can get the "[Awesome](http://www.moreawesomethanyou.com/smf/index.php/topic,15185.0.html)" mod (that enables more functions to mod) and the "[MasterController](http://nraas.wikispaces.com/MasterController#MOD-VERSIONS)" mod.

#### or

Try this console command (Ctrl+Shift+C) and enter `testingCheatsEnabled` (maybe?) and experiment.

Comment: Thanks!  I have tried the command but it didn't work so I will just have to try and install the mods.

Comment: I don't know anything about how commands work in Sims 3, but based on the cheat ones, try `testingCheatsEnabled` instead.

Comment: `testingcheatsenabled` won't allow >8 sims per household. You'll need `MasterController`. In addition, install `NRaas PortraitPanel` to see more than 8 sim icons.